# PHP / MySql if '1' echo "Ok" else if '0' echo "No"

Tags: php, mysql

Phpmyadmin:

[Phpmyadmin Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85BmL.png)

```
if (mysql_query("SELECT setup FROM users") === 1) {

echo "One";

} else if (mysql_query("SELECT setup FROM users") === 0) {

echo "Zero";

}
```

On register. As defined: 0.

If table shows 0, echo Zero.
Else if table shows ID 1, echo One.

How is this done?

Solution:

```
$setup = mysql_query("SELECT setup FROM users");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($setup);

if ($row['setup'] == 0) {
    echo "Zero.";
} else {
    echo "One!";
}
```

Comment: mysql_query is obsolete and it's returning a resource for the result not a number of records, What exactly you want to retrieve from the query ?

Comment: First of all: You shouldn't use `mysql_query` anymore, since it is deprecated. Use `mysqli` instead. Secondly, you are only executing a query here. What you would have to do is `fetch` the returned rows afterwards. You can do that with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` - but as said, it's deprecated.

Comment: [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns either a resource (on success) or `FALSE` (on error). The value it returns is **never** `=== 1` or `=== 0`. The [`===` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) produces a `TRUE` value when the two operands have the same type and value (they are identical).

Comment: If we do not use a query. How can I do this?

If `setup` is at 0, I want to echo something, else if the `setup` is at 1, I wan't to echo something else.

I have tried it with a function, won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

First of all use mysqli

```
//$connection = your mysqli connection. Dont use mysql
```

Then properly write query if you need admin row

```
$query = "SELECT `setup` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `username` = 'admin'";
```

Then execute query

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Then search for $setup value

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $setup = $row['setup'];
}
```

Then echo what you need

```
if ($setup == 1) {    
    echo "One";    
} else if ($setup == 0) {    
    echo "Zero";    
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a `while` loop for a single database record?

Comment: the answer isnt about the while loop. its about getting 0 to = something and 1 to  = something_else when you get it from the database.   thank you standej

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp). The 'Example (MySQLi Procedural)' example is similar to what you want.

Snippet:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Changing

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT setup FROM users";
```

then

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

to your various if checks should suffice. Not the cleanest. Seems like you could just print out the value of setup? Good luck!

Comment: I think `this` did the work.

$setup = mysql_query("SELECT setup FROM users");
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($setup);
      
      if ($row['setup'] == 0) {
       echo "Zero.";
      } else {
       echo "One!";
      }